# How would I track the output of a program through a regularly updated text file on the cloud?

Tags: azure, output, cloud

I am working on a simple project to start getting used to working with the cloud beyond the tutorials given by Azure. I have a very simple program which updates a text file every few minutes with some new data. How could I display this data to a web page / web app?

Very sorry if this is already a post somewhere on here, I wasn't quite sure how to put this into words to search it without finding things about Azure's monitoring extensions.

Comment: That's fine! have you tried to deploy your web application to azure webapp? can you update the error in the question which you were facing.

Comment: There isn't really an error yet, I'm more looking for a place to start. Whenever I try looking this stuff up on Google, it gives me guides for the monitoring extensions in Azure.

Comment: Create an Azure Blob Storage account and a container inside it, update your code to upload the text file to blob container, use azure Blob Storage SDK for your programming language to upload the text file to the container. Then, Deploy your updated application to your Azure App Service/Azure webapp.